# Run JavaScript in bookmark on 2 different pages

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a requirement to run JavaScript as bookmarks on two different pages in Chrome. Suppose on Page 1 I get few fields data using JavaScript and then I have to populate other fields on Page 2 using JavaScript

Example:

Salary field on Page 1

Take data via JavaScript

Populate Compensation fields on Page 2, with data from Salary field on Page 1.

I just wanted to know is this possible?

Comment: For such real time changes you need to implement socket.io.
You can use Pusher and atmosphere as well for example.

Comment: is there any other way without implementation of socket.io, because it is a small requirement of moving data of 3-4 fields from one page to another page ?

Comment: Do you want to do this in real-time ? Like as soon as you change a value in tab1, the other tab content gets updated? Or its ok for you to refresh the page for tab2?
For first case socket is the only good solution. For other case you can use web storage

Comment: I will try with localStorage, this might work. any other suggestions. Please let me know Thanks !

Comment: It is okay for me to refresh the page, or the even like one can close the browser and reopen after few minutes. But this might not work, because the link gets changing every time its dynamic. any suggestions for dynamic links ?

Comment: Cool then go ahead with localStorage. Use its setter and getter methods.

Comment: the link keeps changing, like dynamic with respect to the person logged in, so this localStorage might not work. If it can work, please let me know how ?

Comment: localStorage has nothing to do with the URL. Its just a limited storage on your browser that helps you set and get values. So as long as you have javascript on your webpage and the name of the key that you used while setting the value, you can get the value back on any page. Regardless of the URL.

Comment: Can you please let me know how this localStorage can be run as Bookmarks ? Like the users will click a bookmark button and values will get stored. In bookmark I tried using this locaStorage in javascript but it didn't worked.